# replacing white space with different color from the bottom of the webpage

Tags: html, css, forms

I have [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/237/) in which I want to replace the white space from the bottom with different background color.

The `background-color` which I want is `#F5F5F5`.

[image]

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the CSS codes in the fidle so that I am able to replace white space from the bottom with the `background color: #F5F5F5`

I tried changing `margin: 0 auto 100px;` to  `margin: 0 auto 0;` from the fiddle but for some reasons I am still white-space at the bottom on the web-page.

Comment: Maybe think about it slightly different. If you set the body { background-color: #BFBFBF; } solves the immediate issue, but of course then your navigation is that color as well, instead of white. But, then you can actually set the background color on the .auction-row { background-color: #FFF; }

Comment: @BretLipscomb I have attached the screenshot above. Maybe, it makes more clear now. I want to get rid of the white-spacing from the bottom marked with an arrow sign.

Comment: I understand you want the whitespace below the form gone, but there is nothing below it. If the Browser window is taller than the content it has to generate something and the default is whitespace. Setting the background color to F5F5F5 or BFBFBF (or whatever else you want) will give the entire window the same background when the form stops.

Comment: `margin: 0 auto 0;` for the form is correct, did you save the changes?

Comment: @cfreear Yes, its correct but on a big-screen monitor, I am still seeing the white-space at the bottom. On my laptop, its working perfectly fine but **on a big-screen monitor, I still can see the white-space at the bottom**

Comment: You are required to post your markup and code here, not a jsfiddle. [mcve] A fiddle can compliment your example but not be used in its stead.

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove lines from CSS:
Line 1: `// General CSS`
Line 328: `// End General CSS`
Because // is not valid CSS comment and causes first definitions after them to be invalid.

2) The problem is the `.form` class:

```
.form {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

The line: `margin: 0 auto 100px;` creates a margin-bottom of 100px which is creating that empty space.

Instead you can put a padding bottom to your page:

```
.login-page {
    background-color: #BFBFBF;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

3) For larger screens where the content doesn't fill the whole height of the window:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    background-color:green;
}
```

4) Another problem, the style.css is linked *BEFORE* boostrap.css in your html which is resetting the html and body background color, so put your style.css link **AFTER** boostrap and my solution will work.

[image: High Res screenshot]

Comment: Do I need to change the `margin: 0 auto 100px;` to `margin: 0 auto 0px;` ?

Comment: Yes or you can leave it margin: 0 auto;

Comment: Yes, its correct but on a big-screen monitor, I am still seeing the white-space at the bottom. On my laptop, its working perfectly fine but on a **big-screen monitor, I still can see the white-space at the bottom**

Comment: I have update my answer, where to add the padding, in .login-page class.

Comment: If I remove  `padding-bottom: 100px;` from `.login-page`  class and changing `margin: 0 auto 100px;` to `margin: 0 auto 0px;` I can still see white space at the bottom on big screen but not on my laptop.

Comment: Add html, body height 100% and background color as in my answer.

Comment: It is still present on the big screen desktop.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this background color on

```
html {
  background-color: #BFBFBF;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @user5447339 modified my answer because I think you picked the wrong color in your question

Answer (score 0):

The major problem is with the `.form` change `margin: 0 auto 100px;` to `margin: 0 auto;` in `.form` class and add `min-height: 100vh` to `.login-page` class like this.
You can checkout the update in fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/241/

```
            .login-page{
                 min-height: 100vh
            }  
            .form {
                background: #FFFFFF;
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                box-sizing: content-box;
                padding: 50px;
                text-align: center;
                box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
            }
```